# Sibling attribute binding in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I am a relative Ember newbie, so I may be missing something obvious here. I'm trying to build a custom view for a Bootstrap accordion. I'm using relative views for this, and while it is working, I'd like to understand if I can simplify a little bit. Specifically, I'd like to know if it's possible to make the `href` computed property of the embedded `toggleView` dependent on the `elementId` of the embedded `bodyView.` Here's the top level view, which is a collection:

```
App.AccordionView = Em.CollectionView.extend({
  headingTemplateName: 'accordion-heading',
  innerTemplateName: 'accordion-inner',
  tagName: 'div',
  classNames: ['accordion'],
  contentBinding: 'controller.content',
```

The item view corresponds to the DOM element with the `accordion-group` css class.

```
  itemViewClass: Em.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    classNames: ['accordion-group'],
    target: null,
    template: Em.Handlebars.compile("{{view view.headingView contentBinding='view.content'}}{{view view.bodyView viewName='bodyViewInstance' contentBinding='view.content'}}"),

    headingView: Em.View.extend({
      tagName: 'div',
      template: Em.Handlebars.compile("{{view view.toggleView contentBinding='view.content'}}"),
      classNames: ['accordion-heading'],
      toggleView: Em.View.extend({
        tagName: 'div', // Can be an 'a'
        templateNameBinding: 'parentView.parentView.parentView.headingTemplateName',
        classNames: ['accordion-toggle'],
        attributeBindings: ['dataToggle:data-toggle', 'dataParent:data-parent', 'href'],
        dataToggle: 'collapse',
        dataParent: function() {
          return this.get('parentView.parentView.parentView.elementId');
        }.property(),
```

Note that I've made the `href` property dependent on the `target` field in the item view.

```
        href: function() {
          return "#" + this.get('parentView.parentView.target');
        }.property('parentView.parentView.target')
      })
    }),
    bodyView: Em.View.extend({
      tagName: 'div',
      template: Em.Handlebars.compile("{{view view.innerView contentBinding='view.content'}}"),
      classNames: ['accordion-body', 'collapse'],
```

This field is set when the `bodyView` embedded view instance is inserted into the DOM.

```
      didInsertElement: function() {
        this.get('parentView').set('target', this.get('elementId'));
      },
      innerView: Em.View.extend({
        tagName: 'div',
        classNames: ['accordion-inner'],
        templateNameBinding: "parentView.parentView.parentView.innerTemplateName"
      })
    })
  })
});
```

That all works. However, I'd like to do something like this in the `toggleView`:

```
href: function() {
  return "#" + this.get('parentView.parentView.bodyViewInstance.elementId');
}.property('parentView.parentView.bodyViewInstance.elementId')
```

When I do, I get the following error, and I'm not sure I understand why:

```
Error: Something you did caused a view to re-render after it rendered but before it was inserted into the DOM.
```

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm looking to do?

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle showing this? You can use this as a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/odigity/PkT8x/

Comment: Sherwin, ok, this one (jsfiddle.net/WksUz/2) seems to be working. Also, if you change the href property to return the value of parentView.parentView.bodyViewInstance.elementId, and specify the property dependence on that as well, you can reproduce the issue. However, it seems to be a deprecation warning now rather than an error.